# communicate with a process in utf-8 on a cp1252 consoless

Tags: python, windows, utf-8, cp1252

I need to control a program by sending commands in utf-8 encoding to its standard input. For this I run the program using `subprocess.Popen()`:

```
proc = Popen("myexecutable.exe", shell=True, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
proc.stdin.write(u'ééé'.encode('utf_8'))
```

If I run this from a cygwin utf-8 console, it works. If I run it from a windows console (encoding ='cp1252') this doesn't work. Is there a way to make this work without having to install a cygwin utf-8 console on each computer I want it to run from ? (NB: I don't need to output anything to console)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. The Windows console can't handle Unicode. How do you expect to force it to handle it?

Comment: You are right, but since I don't need the Windows console, I'd like to know if I could run my programs outside the windows console and make them communicate together in utf-8. In effect, I don't need to output anything on the console.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if this caveat, from the [subprocess documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen), is relevant:

> The only reason you would need to specify shell=True on Windows is where the command you wish to execute is actually built in to the shell, eg dir, copy. You don’t need shell=True to run a batch file, nor to run a console-based executable.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to force utf-8 pipes? Couldn't you do something like

```
import sys
current_encoding = sys.stdout.encoding
...
proc.stdin.write(u'ééé'.encode(current_encoding))
```

EDIT: I wrote this answer before you edited your question. I guess this is not what you're looking for, then, is it?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I want to force 'myexecutable.exe' to support utf-8 as standard input. I guess this is not possible